# Set feture id at creation

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

How can I set the `ol.Feature` id when creating it.

Examples and results so far:

```
    // attempt 1
    var fea = new ol.Feature({  id : 123 });
    console.log(fea);

    // attempt 2                
    var fea = new ol.Feature();
    fea.id = 123;
    console.log(fea);

    // attempt 3
    var fea = new ol.Feature();
    fea.id = "123";
    console.log(fea);
```

Results:

Attempt 1:

[image: attempt 1]

Attempt 2:

[image]

Attempt 3:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creation use `feature.setId(id)`

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/apidoc/ol.Feature.html#setId

Comment: Wow, ok, thanks! Does it have a way to set it in "constructor"?

Comment: No way ... you gotta use the method.